# How to add an additional source path into Grails application?

Tags: grails

How could I configure a Grails application in a way that `run-app` and `war` would take into account some external source path `../external/src`?

I'd like not creating a separate grails plugin for that.

**UPD**. Thanks to Ian Roberts, there is a solution. But there is an additional wish appeared. I want that external source (which is large enough) would be used for searching for missed classes only. Not like everything from there is put into the `*.war` now. (That could be achieved with a jar optimizer at least.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of source directories to be compiled is a property of the `projectCompiler`, which you can add to in a suitable `_Events.groovy` block. Try this:

```
eventCompileStart = {
  projectCompiler.srcDirectories << "${basedir}/../external/src"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well! I just wish that external source path would be used for missed classes only. Now everything from there is added to the war. But it's good anyway.

Comment: @PavelVlasov less than ideal but you can use `eventCreateWarStart` to clean things up.

Comment: NB: using a GString there causes grails 2.x's recompiling watch dog to fail. Java strings are okay.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to expand on the above answer (which is correct).  The _Events.groovy file goes in the scripts directory.  If you want to share "everything" in the class you can do as above, or specify the specific package as below (I'm trying to share GWT between two).

```
eventCompileStart = {
    projectCompiler.srcDirectories << "${basedir}/src/directory/org/mypackage/mustbe/shared"
}
```